# How to get its user id of a post through postid when comments the post?

Tags: python, mysql, orm, flask, sqlalchemy

Environment: MySQL with Foreign-Key association, and SQLALchemy with Flask.

- Table(User): id, username
- Table(Post): id, content

  user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
- Table(Comment): id, content, post_author_id

  user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))

  comment_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id'))

When Tom comments on a post published by Jackie, like this:

```
http://myblog.com/post/<postid>
```

I need to save this comment, and at the same time, according to `<postid>`, I want to save the user id of this post as post_author_id into table Comment. That means table Comment saves Tom's user_id and Jackie's user_id. how to write this SQLALchemy line?

```
post_author_id = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would like to get this information dynamically rather than storing it as another column in your database since this data (`post_author_id`) already exists within your `posts` table (Post.user_id).

To do this, you can use SQLAlchemy's [Hybrid Attributes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html).

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String, nullable=False)


class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = relationship(User)
    content = Column(String)

class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('posts.id'))
    post = relationship(Post)
    content = Column(String)

    @hybrid_property
    def post_author_id(self):
        return self.post.user_id
```

There are a variety of ways you can write the `Comment.post_author_id`